# How to use image generating php when php file is outside doc root

Tags: php

I have a file, `showcaptcha.php`, that outputs an image.

I was referencing it like this:

```
<img src='/security/showcaptcha.php'>
```

It worked fine, so no problem with the code inside `showcaptcha.php`.

However, now I moved that php file outside doc root for security reasons. Putting php files outside doc root is good practice b/c it makes it harder for hackers to access any source code.

but now, what do I put in the src of my img?

```
<img src='???showcaptcha.php'>
```

or

```
<img src='<?php echo ??? ?>'>
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do it since using src on the img tag means that the web server has to be able to "see" the PHP file.

Comment: Here's a thought, leave a stub named `showcaptcha.php` in the security directory and have it do nothing but `require` the real `showcaptcha.php` in its new location. That leaves virtually nothing visible.

Comment: Will you have to generate the desired image when the page loads and place it in an accessible directory? You may end up with a maintenance issue as this goes on (lots of images), though you may be able to limit that by using the session ID as part of the image name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your real code in a directory that is in the PHP include path (which is outside of the document root) and leave a stub in the security directory that does nothing more than `require('showcaptcha.php');`. Someone digging around is only going to know that that file exists someplace but if they are in the document root they won't be able to see or find it.

Comment: voted up for reminding me that require *is* the file itself, for all practical purposes except hacking.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are using a `public` folder (or other name) to put your public files, right? Something like this:

```
- src/
- public/
  - index.php
- .htaccess
```

In this case you are not able to use `../showcaptcha.php`, then you need to put it your root `.htaccess`. If the root `.htaccess` is sending the user to `public` folder, then that you need is create a new rule pointing an `url` to the showcaptcha file.
Something like:

```
...
# access the `images/captcha.jpg` to get the result
RewriteRule ^images/captcha.jpg$ ./path/to/showcaptcha.php

# send all urls that not is a folder or a directory to public/index.php, then init the magic with friendly url in this file
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .$ public/index.php
```

Comment: This didn't work. I used `../vendor/myvendor/captcha.jpg` for the actual path, but I get a 500 error in the rewrite module.

Comment: Thee 500 error is a internal error (in your php script). But, I think that you url `../vendor/myvendor/captcha.jpg` is not right... You `.htaccess` is like this `RewriteRule ^images/captcha.jpg$ ./path/to/showcaptcha.php`?

Comment: No, because my `.htaccess` is under `public`. I'm not sure how to move it. If it's under public I think that's causing my problem because maybe `../path` is not a valid url.